# URL Hack "Back to List" Links

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there anyway to URL hack the back to link portion of default pages. Often time the navigation is incorrect and sending users to random portions of the site. Is there some sort of session variable being stored or something?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That back to List is a very confusing part of Salesforce. Most people assume it is a breadcrumb to get back to the previous page but it is not, it remembers the last "List" you viewed and will take you back to that. For most admin users this actually links back to something in the setup pages.

It works as it should, but many question it's usefulness all together as it is very confusing.

See this link:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp4fAAC

It's a common complaint for the last 7 years.

My advise for now. Tell your users to ignore it all together and use the back button on the browser. Unfortunately there isn't anything you can do to remove/change it currently.

Comment: One of these little things that annoy me every day...

Answer (score 1):

The "Back To List" link takes you back to the last ListView, on the last unadultrated SalesForce page that you viewed, if and only if you navigated through a link on that list.  Doesn't matter where you go in SF after that, or if you navigate through other ListViews if they're on custom VisualForce pages.  From that point fwd all "Back To List" links will point back to that last listview of theirs that you navigated through.